# How to get value from input field in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to get data from input field in React Typescipt?

**Code:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const AuthPage: React.FC = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  })

  const changeHandler = (event: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    setForm({ ...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  }

  const showState = () => {
    console.log(form)
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col s6 offset-s3">
        <h1>URL Shortener</h1>
        <div className="card blue darken-4">
          <div className="card-content white-text">
            <span className="card-title">Authorization</span>
            <div>
              <div className="input-field">
                <input
                  placeholder="Enter Email"
                  id="email"
                  type="text"
                  name="email"
                  className="yellow-input"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-field">
                <input
                  placeholder="Enter Password"
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  className="yellow-input"
                  onChange={changeHandler}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="card-action">
            <button className="btn yellow darken-4" style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
              Sign in
            </button>
            <button onClick={showState} className="btn grey lighten-1 black-text">
              Sign up
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AuthPage
```

**This is error message:**

```
"Property 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.  TS2339".
"Property 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.  TS2339".
and second error "Type '(event: React.KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent<Element>': altKey, charCode, ctrlKey, getModifierState, and 8 more.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2101, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'"
```

Comment: can you change the event type to any and try it again.

Comment: @IsaToltar Usually setting types to `any` isn't a satisfactory solution, because in doing so you abandon type safety altogether. If your TypeScript code is full of `any`s, you might as well be using vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.KeyboardEvent` is a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). You can specify the element type to which it's attached, like this: `React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>`.

In addition, you probably need to change `event.target` (which may or may not be the element on which the event handler is registered, due to [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)) to `event.currentTarget` (which is guaranteed to be the element on which it's registered).